# Forward all incoming and outgoing traffic to port 53 iptables?

Tags: linux, vpn, android, iptables

Recently I have just ran into a problem. I was using bookvpn VPN on my android phone which came to be very slow now a days.

- I wanted to try some different VPN but My ISP only allows VPN to run over port 53.
- I wanted to redirect all my incoming and outgoing traffic to port 53. So I can try some different VPN. The problem is some of those VPN run over port 1195,1227 etc.

So far I have tried this line of code no luck.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 1:65535 -j DNAT --to 53
```

Is it possible to forward all incoming and outgoing traffic or just traffic from port 1195 to port 53 to establish VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the redirect like this:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1:65535 -j DNAT --to-

destination 192.168.1.2:53
```

All connections to 192.168.1.2 (chage this with your local IP address) will be redirected to port 53.

-or-

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1:65535 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
```

But in the case of VPN, why not configure your own VPN client and server to run through port 53 ?